# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery' to type 'PagedList.IPagedList'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, pagedlist

I am trying to use pagination for a ASP.NET MVC 5 application.
I have used [X.PagedList](https://github.com/kpi-ua/X.PagedList/)
 I have implemented it correctly in a simple object, but I have problem when implementing it with a more complex object. For example like when I have relationship like Posts and Comments in a forum.

My models have the following structure

```
public class PublicReport
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int PublicReportID { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }       
    ...
    public virtual Institutions Institution { get; set; }
    ...
}   

public class Institutions
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int InstitutionID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

In the controller is the following code

```
public ActionResult ListReports(int? page)
{
    var pageNumber = page ?? 1;     
    var listOfReports = db.PublicReport.OrderByDescending(d => d.CreatedDate).Where(c => c.CategoryId == 1).ToList();
    listOfReports.ToPagedList(pageNumber, 3);
    return View("ReportList", listOfReports);
}
```

In the View (PartialView) the relevant part is

```
@model IEnumerable<RENJK.Models.PublicReport>

@using PagedList.Mvc;
@using PagedList;   

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="consult-post-sec">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)</p>
                <div class="consult-posts-by">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Institution.Name)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }), PagedListRenderOptions.OnlyShowFivePagesAtATime)
```

The error that I get is

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[RENJK.Models.PublicReport]' to type 'PagedList.IPagedList'.

The problem seems to be in the view in the line of code where i want to display the ListPager because the error wont show if i remove that.

What can I do in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not assigning the results of `ToPagedList()` to a variable (and therefore not returning `IPagedList<PublicReport>`, just `IEnumerable<PublicReport>`). Change your code to

```
public ActionResult ListReports(int? page)
{
    var pageNumber = page ?? 1;     
    var listOfReports = db.PublicReport.OrderByDescending(d => d.CreatedDate).Where(c => c.CategoryId == 1).ToList();
     var pagedList = listOfReports.ToPagedList(pageNumber, 3); // modify
     return View("ReportList", pagedList ); // modify
 }
```

Note also your model in the view should be

```
@model IPagedList<RENJK.Models.PublicReport>
```

and then there is no need for the case. It can be just

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action(....`
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought that ToPagedList operates directly on listOfReports